# Re-calculate the score for all other groups when the condition is met

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, cluster-analysis

I have a dataframe (df) that contains the user with their vectors (x1), group number, group vector (x2), p2, counts the members of each group (k), and the threshold for each group.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['user 1', 'user 2', 'user 3', 'user 4', 'user 5'],
                   'group': [1, 0, 0, 2, 1],
                   'x1': [[0.2, 0.3, 0.5], [0.3, 0.3, 0.4], [0.4, 0.4, 0.2], [0.2, 0.1, 0.7], [0.5,0.3,0.2]],
                   'x2': [[0.5, 0.2, 0.3], [0.4, 0.2, 0.4], [0.4, 0.2, 0.4], [0.5, 0.1, 0.4], [0.5, 0.2, 0.3]],
                   'p2': [0.342, 0.231, 0.231, 0.411, 0.342],
                   'k': [2, 2, 2, 1, 2],
                   'threshold': [0.6, 0.9, 0.9, 0.8, 0.6],})
```

I calculated for each user, the score (S) with respect to its group by using the code:

[image]

output:

```
user    group   x1  x2  p2  k   threshold   score
0   user 1  1   [0.2, 0.3, 0.5] [0.5, 0.2, 0.3] 0.342   2   0.6 0.909357
1   user 2  0   [0.3, 0.3, 0.4] [0.4, 0.2, 0.4] 0.231   2   0.9 0.586580
2   user 3  0   [0.4, 0.4, 0.2] [0.4, 0.2, 0.4] 0.231   2   0.9 0.846320
3   user 4  2   [0.2, 0.1, 0.7] [0.5, 0.1, 0.4] 0.411   1   0.8 1.437956
4   user 5  1   [0.5, 0.3, 0.2] [0.5, 0.2, 0.3] 0.342   2   0.6 0.558480
```

I want to re-calculate the score with respect to all other groups, If the score is higher than the threshold.

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to re-calculate the score with respect to all other groups, If the score is higher than the threshold."? Your score formula seems independent of the threshold?